# Stop SAS from replacing missing value with 0

Tags: sas, missing-data

I've got a dependent variable with 8 missing values.  It's currently a quantitative variable.  However, I want to bucketize them into the median and below; and above the median, but while preserving the 8 missing values.  The following code is replacing the missing values with zeroes and I don't understand why.

```
data baseline_all_disc2;
set baseline_all3;
if health_state_m eq . then health_state_m_disc=.; /*This line of code doesn't seem to be working*/
if health_state_m LE 60 then health_state_m_disc=0;
else health_state_m_disc=1;
run;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using IF/ELSE IF, not just multiple IF statements. Your code is working correctly the way you've shown it.

First IF -> health_state_m_disc is set to missing.
Second IF -> LE 60 - Missing is considered less than so this evaluates as true as well. Switch to using IF/ELSE IF to avoid the second IF statement every being evaluated.

Adding the ELSE, this will work.

```
data baseline_all_disc2;
set baseline_all3;
if health_state_m eq . then health_state_m_disc=.; /*This line of code doesn't seem to be working*/
ELSE if health_state_m LE 60 then health_state_m_disc=0;
else health_state_m_disc=1;
run;
```

EDIT: another option if you have multiple missing values coded, ie ., .A-.Z
A benefit of the MISSING() function is that it works on both character and numeric variables the same.

```
data baseline_all_disc2;
set baseline_all3;
if missing(health_state_m) then call missing(health_state_m_disc); /*This line of code doesn't seem to be working*/
ELSE if health_state_m LE 60 then health_state_m_disc=0;
else health_state_m_disc=1;
run;
```

Comment: You really should use `missing()` instead of `eq .`.  Otherwise special missing values will not be caught and so will still cause target variable to be set to zero.

Comment: In my entire SAS career I've seen very, very little usage of special missing values. They are useful and do exist but it's a rare use case IME.

Answer (score 1):

Missing values are considered less than numeric values. The line `if health_state_m LE 60 then health_state_m_disc=0;` is changing it to 0. For your second `if` statement, add a missing value check.

```
if(NOT missing(health_state_m) AND health_state_m LE 60) then health_state_m_disc=0;
```